# How to clear combobox value in the windows form using c#?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am building an windows application..So in my combobox i have 2 feilds 
 "familyHead" and "familyMember" so based up on the user selection i want to show
  the records.Suppose if he select familyHead then i will show familyHead details
  i am providing first,last,next,clear buttons.

so i captured combobox value like below:

```
 position = this.cbPosition.GetItemText(this.cbPosition.SelectedItem);
```

so now,i got the position so if the user not selected the position.Then i will
  show the message please select the position.So everything is fine.

But, the problem here is when the user click on the clear button.After that he 
  click on First button on the form,It is not asked please select the position,
  directly displays the details on the form based on previous value.

Under clear button:

I removed postion and also text of the combobox like below:

```
position = "";
cbPosition.Text = "";
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'd say you should set the selected index to -1, or something like that

```
cbPosition.SelectedIndex = -1;
```

Comment: Glad of having been of some help, and in case it worked please mark it as answered

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider to add a "blank item" to the combobox so the user can always clear his pick